# TeraData Account validation in SSIS

Tags: c#, ssis, teradata

I am trying to connect to Teradata via SSIS package and i want to validate the credentials used to connect the Teradata. Validation involves following check

1. User account is not valid
2. User Valid but password expired
3. User account is valid but locked, I guess if i am sending trying the correct credentials to connect and account is locked then there must be something returned in response that indicate that the account is locked.

If any of the three point could be implemented then it would do the trick

Answer (score 0):

#1 and #3 will return a generic *8017 The UserId, Password or Account is invalid* error, but for security reasons there's no detail what actually caused that error.

#2 returns *3032 User password has expired* warning (error when there is/was already another session logged on), the only statement allowed in that session is `MODIFY USER` to change the password.